# HTML not interpreted with JQuery Mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have some HTML-encodet text in a database, and when I retrieve it I HTML-decode it. The problem is that the HTML tags are not interpreted, but displayed.

If I have the following paragraph:

```
&lt;p&gt;&#13;&#10;&#9;Hello World&lt;/p&gt;&#13;&#10;
```

It will output:

```
<p> Hello World </p>
```

I output the code as following:

> @Server.HtmlDecode(Model.Message)

What simple thing might I be missing?

Comment: Show us the code that renders the html. Also, there is no reason to html encode text just to save it in the db.

Comment: The data comes from user input, I therefore html-encodes it.

Comment: I think this gets interpreted from jquery-mobile. I have a similiar issue with a selection option caption: `&lt;all&gt;` being converted to `<all></all>` by jquery-mobile.

Comment: @Dofs You only need to html-encode untrusted input when you *display* it.

Comment: @ZippyV, you are correct, it is an old design error, which probably should be fixed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `Html.Raw` helper:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Message)
```

Make sure that you have sanitized the input before since the Html.Raw helper will output the HTML as-is without encoding.